# Limit the facebook page feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get a feed (preferably JSON) of a facebook page, limited by a certain number? Main reason being we only want the most recent 10, and perceive that it would reduce waiting time (download and server processing).

I'm currently using the seemingly undocumented feeds/page.php url, like so:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=1234

I tried adding limit parameter (also max-results, count, etc) but to no avail. As far as I can tell it can't be done using the Graph API either.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the facebook url as:
$url = $pageId."/feed?access_token=".$accessToken."&limit=".$numberOfRecordsToPull."&fields=

Comment: this is the right answer, and it could be verified on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 0):

No it seems not. You can modify the received feed to limit the number of posts, if necessary.